# could anyone explain to me how this piece of program works?

Tags: c

I saw this program in a page and I would like to use it in my documentation. especially at the level of the while loop

```
unsigned char calculation(const unsigned char *string)
{
    static uint8_t Value;
    const   uint8_t StartValue = 0;
    Value = StartValue;
    char CRVT[2] = "\r\v";

    strcat((char *)string, CRVT);
    while(*string)
    {
        Value = crc8table[Value ^ *string];
        string++;
    }
    return Value;
}
```

Comment: What is your exact question? Which line do you not understand? Have you tried to embed this code into an application and run it with different inputs and step through it with a debugger?

Comment: Also, don't tag your question as C++ **and** C, because there is no C++ at all. Don't do this! They are very different languages.

Comment: `CRVT` isn't null-terminated, making your `strcat` undefined. And casting a const pointer to a non-const one also invokes UB

Comment: Don't use this code for anything. It has errors. It has potential errors depending on code not posted. It's confusing (aka hard to understand). Instead focus on the problem you need to solve and write/find code that solves the problem in a clear, easy to understabd way.

Comment: I said above that I would like to be explained at the level of the while loop. I am a beginner and I had not seen this case where we put a string in the while loop

Answer (score 2):

The code posted is fairly buggy and doesn't work as intended. Supposedly it should add CR+VT at the end of a line, CR meaning carriage return and VT meaning vertical tab.

However, the line `char CRVT[2] = "\r\v";` does not allocate room for the null terminator, so upon calling `strcat`, the program will crash and burn.

Casting a `const char*` to `char*` and then writing to it is highly questionable practice and might invoke poorly-defined behavior.

As for `Value = crc8table[Value ^ *string];` it is simply some CRC table look-up with pre-calculated FCS (frame check sequence) values for some CRC-8 algorithm. The `^` is the XOR operator, which is used when calculating a CRC. What it does in this code, as part of the table look-up, is anyone's guess. It doesn't make any sense.

The `static` qualifier of `Value` fills no purpose, since that variable is reset in run-time.

Overall I wouldn't use this code, since it has such low quality. It was not written by a professional, but some beginner.

Comment: Thankfully an educational answer instead of the usual whining and downvotes.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. but what about the while loop? how does it work? for my part I would say that it controls the String bit by bit but what i know is that with the lookup-tabele the CRC is calculate byte by byte

Comment: @mendoul It simply checks for the string null terminator and then steps the local pointer variable `string` up one item. It is equivalent to `for(; *string != '\0'; string++) {...}`.